# XJC : MAVEN Plugin Generating JAXBElement classes

Tags: maven, plugins, xjc, jaxbelement

Maven :

```xml
<execution>
 <id>cdm-generate-Oracle</id>

  <goals>
     <goal>
        generate</goal>
  </goals>

 <configuration>

     <schemaDirectory>src\main\resources\xsd\clients</schemaDirectory>
     <verbose>true</verbose>

        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>*.xsd</include>          

        </schemaIncludes>

        <bindingDirectory>src\main\resources\xsd\clients</bindingDirectory>

        <bindingIncludes>
            <bindingInclude>*.xjb</bindingInclude>
        </bindingIncludes>

        <generatePackage>com.adp.smartconnect.client.oraclecloud</generatePackage>

        <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
        <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
 </configuration>

 </execution>
```

XSD :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                          xmlns:xoracle="http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xsd:element name="DATA_DS">
            <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ARCHIVEPACTID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DELIVERYOPTIONID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:long"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PAYROLLACTIONID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="G_1" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="FILE_FRAGMENT" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="PAYSLIP" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                      <xsd:element name="REP_CATEGORY_NAME"
                                                      minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                                                      <xsd:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0">
                                                      <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                                      <xsd:sequence>
                                                      <xsd:element name="request_id" minOccurs="0"
                                                      type="xsd:long"/>
                                                      <xsd:element name="FLOW_NAME" minOccurs="0"
                                                      type="xsd:string"/>
```

Binding :

```
    <jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:/C:/Murali-CDM/src/main/resources/xsd/clients/USOnlinePayslip_GSE_R9_062415.xsd"  node="/xs:schema">
          <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
       </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Generated Class :

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "DATA_DS")
    public class DATADS {

        @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "ARCHIVEPACTID", namespace = "http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "DELIVERYOPTIONID", namespace = "http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "G_1", namespace = "http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "PAYROLLACTIONID", namespace = "http://www.adp.com/smartclound/v0.9", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
        })
        @XmlMixed
        protected List<Serializable> content;
    ================================
```

Issue :     Trying to generate JAXB Objects from the xsd. The xjc plugin is generating JAXBElements . I am trying to get rid of the JAXBElement generation using a binding. Not successful ?    What is wrong with my binding ?

Comment: What's the output (java class) that you expect/want to get?

Comment: We are looking for a class  public DATA_ds ( private int ARCHIVEPACTID)

Comment: It believe the result you get is because you are using `mixed="true"`. Have a look at the documentation here: https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. This resolved the issue

Comment: Maybe you could post an answer yourself describing what you ended up doing so other people seeing this question can profit from it too? You can also accept your own answer so it's clear that the question is not open any longer.